# Why image is empty if I set source by the story board?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I'm writing a custom WP8 control and I need to change source of an image from the storyboard that is managed by the VisualStateManager.

My XAML

```
<Style TargetType="local:StateImageButton">

    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="ImageStretch" Value="Uniform" />

    <Setter Property="InactiveImage" Value="/StarLine.Controls;component/Resources/StateImageButton/ButtonInactive.png" />
    <Setter Property="DisabledImage" Value="/StarLine.Controls;component/Resources/StateImageButton/ButtonDisabled.png" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:StateImageButton">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" >
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="viewImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0" Value="{TemplateBinding InactiveImage}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="viewImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0" Value="{TemplateBinding DisabledImage}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>

                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Image x:Name="viewImage"
                               Stretch="{TemplateBinding ImageStretch}"
                               Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                               HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                               VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This is a dependency property declaration

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty InactiveImageProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("InactiveImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(StateImageButton), null);

        [TypeConverter(typeof(ImageSourceConverter))]
        public ImageSource InactiveImage
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(InactiveImageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(InactiveImageProperty, value); }
        }
```

And finally a code to change VisualState

```
private void UpdateState()
        {
            if(IsEnabled)
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Normal", false);
            }
            else
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Disabled", false);
            }           
        }
```

All of the parts seems correct but image source doesn't change

Comment: Try by setting  

      Storyboard.TargetProperty as "(Image.Source)"

Comment: Ensure the path of image is correct. Verify
<Setter Property="InactiveImage" Value="/StarLine.Controls;component/Resources/StateImageButton/ButtonInactive.png" />
<Setter Property="DisabledImage" Value="/StarLine.Controls;component/Resources/StateImageButton/ButtonDisabled.png" />
retrieves image exactly.

Comment: All setters are correct it's working correct if I add TemplateBinding directly to the Image element. So I have write a C# code to sole this issue and will return to the VSM when have a free time.